# .after() method recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter

Came across similar code structure a number of times and when I saw this in a `threading.Thread` implementation, I just needed to ask wouldn't the line `self.master.after(100, self.periodicCall)` consume more and more memory as it is a recursive function call... It is, isn't it?

```
class arbitraryClass():
    def __init__(self, master):
        ... # other miscellaneous codes not shown here
        self.periodicCall() # within the __init__() method

    def periodicCall(self): 
        self.doSomething() #arbitrary method
        self.master.after(100, self.periodicCall)
        ... # other miscellaneous codes not shown here
```

Comment: It almost certainly isn't a recursive call but we can't be sure unless you tell us something about the type of `self.master`. Most likely the method arranges to call the `periodicCall` method some time after the first call to the method has returned.

Comment: Hi Duncan. The `self.master` herein is suppose to be the root of the entire program... i.e the same level as where we usually call import statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`periodicCall` method does not call itself directly; it's not a recursive call.

It request tkinter event loop to call the method in given time; no need to worry about memory consumption.

Comment: Hi falsetru. I'd like to thank both you and @Duncan for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The method is not recursive.

The callback is only run once for each call to after(). To call it repeatedly, you need to reregister the callback inside itself.